# How to upload an image to a Json file using the local API in Angular 13

Tags: angular

I can send the **name** data in the json file (local host), but I can not send the **image** file

```
 uploadFile(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0 ) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      this.form.get('image')?.setValue(file);
    } 
  }
    submitForm() {
    var formData: any = new FormData();

    formData.append("name", this.form.get('name')?.value);
    formData.append("image", this.form.get('image')?.value);


    this.http.post<any>(this.API, { data: formData}).subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    )
  }
```

Comment: If ‘image’ is a file input, you should append the .files[0] of that control..

Comment: @MikeOne, I did this operation but it still has a problem.

Comment: Log the 'this.form' and 'formData' to the console. What's the output?

Comment: @Amirhossein Shahbazi, The append operation is performed correctly and the image file values are not sent when sending.
Other values are sent.
      "data": {
        "name": "farzad",
        "image": {}
      }

Comment: Actually.. this is incorrect: { data: formData}. You should just use formData there so Angular will sent the request as multi-part form post.

Comment: @MikeOne, tested
Image data will not be sent